How to resolve the dependency issue in VectorCAST for Microchip source code
I need to do software testing and validation for the PIC16f15214 source code using VectorCAST.
But when I build the environment it shows the "compiler error" / "can't open the 'XYZ.h' file", even after adding the complete path of all the dependencies (includes, source files, handler files), the issue persists.
I am very new to SW testing of PIC microcontrollers.
SW used for Validation: VectorCAST SP3
IDE used for Source code: MPLABxIDE
Microcontroller: PIC16F15214
Compiler: XC8
I tried to add the path of all the dependencies required to build the project. The project is built in MPLAB x IDE without any error. When I am building in the VectorCAST it shows the compiler error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You had to set the include path in VectorCAST. https://cdn.vector.com/cms/content/know-how/_application-notes/AN-ACT-1-009-VectorCAST_Configuring_Source_and_Include_Paths.pdf
